# ¿Cómo traducir este "longstop"?

Tags: traducción, significado, metáfora

Hice una [pregunta en EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334501/what-is-a-longstop-british-i-think) sobre una palabra que me encontré en un texto de Julian Barnes: *longstop*.

(Os dejo tiempo para que leáis la pregunta, la respuesta y los comentarios).

Barnes utiliza una metáfora deportiva para decir que tal vez Dios quiera asumir ese papel de *longstop*. Para ello, utiliza un deporte muy popular en Gran Bretaña y toda la *Commonwealth* (no así en los EEUU): el críquet.

¿Cómo podría traducirse en español *longstop* en esta acepción, a ser posible utilizando alguna metáfora deportiva que sea inteligible por el público hispanohablante?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me encantan estas preguntas. Veamos, la frase traducida sería tal que así:

> Podría disfrutar de ser un especialista en carretera, una compañía de seguros, un XXX.

¿Qué es ese XXX? Según las respuestas y comentarios en la pregunta original, y el tipo de metáfora que quieres emplear, hay que buscar un tipo de jugador de cualquier deporte que represente la última salvaguarda antes del desastre (el tanto del equipo contrario). Lo primero que se me ocurre es, en términos futbolísticos, usar la palabra *portero*. Pero como dicha así tal cual se podría malinterpretar, mi propuesta es usar la palabra **[guardameta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JirBhAj)**, cuya etimología además incluye el verbo *[guardar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JjJWqPL)* en el sentido de *cuidar, preservar*, que concuerda con el sentido de protección de las compañías de seguros, por seguir el símil. A fin de cuentas, un guardameta constituye la última línea defensiva antes del gol, y sólo debe actuar cuando los integrantes de la defensa no hacen bien su trabajo.

Comment: “Especialista en averías” más bien. En mi opinión la mejor traducción es la descriptiva: *última [línea de] defensa*.

Comment: Guardameta me gusta. Una menos (o no) deportiva es [apagaincendios](http://hsbnoticias.com/noticias/deportes/f%C3%BAtbol/james-rodriguez-el-apagaincendios-sera-titular-con-real-madr-206478)

Comment: If you want a football analogy for the longstop imagine a corner kick. It is the goalkeeper's job to keep the ball out but the team often stations one or more defenders in the goal mouth to help him. Those defenders are playing a role more like a longstop. I doubt whether either English or Spanish has a word for them though. I think @angus has a good suggestion although sadly not a sporting one as requested by the OP.

Comment: @mdewey I didn't require the word to be a sporting one - I said "if possible". I think that all of them are good. Yes, the corner kick scenario is the most similar, but there's no word for the position. I also think with angus that "especialista en averías" is more accurate than "especialista en carretera".